# How to do FoldPanelBar inside ScrollPanel in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I tried to do a collapsible FoldPanelBar inside of a ScrollPanel. But it is not loading the contents of the FoldPanelBar. The list control UI inside the fold panel is not even loading. I tried replacing with a regular panel, but the result is the same. Could you please let me know if I am missing something here?

```
import wx
from wx.lib import scrolledpanel
import wx.lib.agw.foldpanelbar as fpb

class MyPanel(wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent=parent, size=parent.GetSize(), style = wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.SetupScrolling()

        csStyle = fpb.CaptionBarStyle()
        csStyle.SetFirstColour(wx.Colour(190, 190, 190, 255))
        csStyle.SetSecondColour(wx.Colour(167, 232, 146, 255))
        csStyle.SetCaptionFont(wx.Font(9, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))

        m_pnl = fpb.FoldPanelBar(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize,
                            fpb.FPB_VERTICAL)

        item = m_pnl.AddFoldPanel("Set 1", collapsed=True, cbstyle=csStyle)

        self.listContainer = wx.ListCtrl(item)
        self.listContainer.InsertColumn(0, 'Column1', width=250)
        self.listContainer.InsertColumn(1, 'Column2', width=150)
        self.listContainer.InsertColumn(2, 'Column3')

        m_pnl.AddFoldPanelWindow(item, self.listContainer)
        btnGo = wx.Button(item, wx.ID_ANY, "Go", size=(50,-1))
        m_pnl.AddFoldPanelWindow(item, btnGo)

        item = m_pnl.AddFoldPanel("Set 2", collapsed=True, cbstyle=csStyle)
        self.listContainer2 = wx.ListCtrl(item, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.listContainer2.InsertColumn(0, 'Column1', width=250)
        self.listContainer2.InsertColumn(1, 'Column2', width=150)
        self.listContainer2.InsertColumn(2, 'Column3')

        m_pnl.AddFoldPanelWindow(item, self.listContainer2)

        self.pnl = m_pnl


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = wx.Frame(None, size=(650, 400), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
    panel = MyPanel(frame)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues with your example. First, the columns will not show in normal list mode of `wx.ListCtrl`. Set the `LC_REPORT` style as follows:

```
    self.listContainer = wx.ListCtrl(item, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
```

Secondary, there is no proper layouting/sizing happening here.

```
# ...
panel = MyPanel(frame)
# Add sizer information for the scrolled panel
szmain = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
szmain.Add(panel.pnl, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 4)
panel.SetSizer(szmain)
```

By applying these changes on wxPython classic 3.0.2 (MSW) at least the controls are layouted so that they fill the frame.

Comment: Thanks! That was it :)

Comment: The list control came up but the scroll bars doesn't show up though when I resize the frame.

Comment: Yes, I also saw that (no scroll bars). As I use neither of ``ScrolledPanel`` nor ``FoldPanelBar`` I am of no help there. Maybe it would be best to not mix them anyway, because they achieve the same (deal with limited space in a window) by different means?

Comment: Essentially it is panel within a panel. Strange that it doesn't work.